# Can I merge like-ID/like-name polygons (collections of arcs) in TopoJSON (or other convenient tool)?

Tags: shapefile, topojson

I've been building TopoJSON maps of US counties from mbostock's us-atlas collection. For most of the states, there is one polygon created per county. Great!

For the state of Michigan, for some reason, every landform is separate in the imported shp file, so the counties that have little islands (out onto the lakes) have multiple polygons with the same county ID and name. I've tried to manually merge the arrays of arcs, and the result is an intersection mess. I've tried reprocessing with different topojson settings, but so far, nothing has done the trick.

For example

... `{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[250]],"id":"26033","properties":{"name":"Chippewa County"}},{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[251]],"id":"26033","properties":{"name":"Chippewa County"}},{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[252]],"id":"26033","properties":{"name":"Chippewa County"}}` ...

Other states' data from the some source correctly include all the arcs in one polygon with one id and one county name, so I'm baffled. What I really want to do is somehow process a shp or topojson file so as to merge these islands and landmasses together.

Comment: 1. Maybe you should consider these id like `class`, as I do, and name them as such. 2. I stay interested by a merging solution. If someone have one: +1 and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and wrote a simple (read: crude and ugly) script to solve it seen here in this github gist: https://gist.github.com/mkessy/7188859

Basically the problem comes from having multiple features of type "Polygon" referring to the same County feature, so when you do a data join using for example the FIPS code as the key, you'll end up with unexpected results since there will be multiple polygons that have the same key.

The solution is simple, merge the group of polygons into a single feature with type "[MultiPolygon](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#multipolygon)." This type can easily be understood by the d3 path function and then you can do data joins etc.

All the script does is iterate through the features and captures the coordinates for the features with the given FIPS code, and creates a new feature by appending all those coordinate arrays. It also re-sums the AREA, SQUARE_MIL, and PERIMETER properties. To use the script you are going to have to generate the GeoJSON directly from the shp file.